# plpgsql Assign a value to a type after the attribute name

Tags: postgresql, plpgsql

I want to assign a value to a type having the attribute name as a character varying.

lets say I have this type

```
create type HelloWorld as (hello character varying, world character varying)


DO
$body$
DECLARE
    attr_name character varying := 'hello'; 
    obj       HelloWorld;
BEGIN
    -- what I want is to do something like this
    obj.attr_name = 'hello';


END;
$body$
LANGUAGE 'plpgsql';
```

Is it possible?

Answer (score 0):

No, it is not possible. The structure of composite type is very static. Dynamic fields are not supported.